# triggering method on a formerly invisible element

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I use two jquery plugins [SlideControl](http://nikorablin.com/slideControl/) and [iCheck](https://github.com/damirfoy/iCheck), then I use this script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('.slideControl').slideControl({
                'lowerBound' : 1,
                'upperBound' : 10
            });
            $('.form-horizontal input').iCheck({
                checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_flat',
                radioClass: 'iradio_flat'
            });
            $("input").on("ifChecked",function(e){
                 $(this).parent().next().removeClass("invisible");
            });
});
```

`$(this).parent().next()` has class `.slideControl`, so it should display as a slider, but it doesn't work. For information, `ifChecked` corresponds to `check` event customized for the `iCheck` api. I tried to add

```
$("input").on("ifChecked",function(e){
          $(this).parent().removeClass("invisible");
          $('.slideControl').slideControl({
                    'lowerBound' : 1,
                    'upperBound' : 10
                });
});
```

it didn't work either. In fact, if I put this last code inside the `slidecontrol` file `slideControl.min.js`, it works. But it isn't very clean, could someone help ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it, it was a little tricky : in fact, when the `ifChecked` is not really synchronous with the checking event, so I had to do that !

```
$("input").on("ifChecked",function(e){
                $(this).parent().addClass('checked');
                $(this).parent().removeClass("invisible");
      $('.slideControl').slideControl({
                'lowerBound' : 1,
                'upperBound' : 10
            });
            });
```

Comment: Tip: `$(this).parent().addClass('checked').removeClass('invisible');`